# How to reverse key order deep on JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to deep reverse the order of all keys in a JavaScript object.

For example:

```js
{
  a: 'val1',
  b: 'val2',
  c: {
    ca: 'val3',
    cb: 'val4'
  }
}
```

Must become:

```js
{
  c: {
    cb: 'val4',
    ca: 'val3'
  },
  b: 'val2',
  a: 'val1'
}
```

I have tried writing a recursive function, but I cannot figure out how to fix it:

```js
function reverseKeys (obj, newObj = {}) {
  Object.keys(obj).reverse().forEach(key => {
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      newObj = reverseKeys(obj[key], {})
    }
    newObj[key] = obj[key]
  })
  return newObj
}
```

**Solution inspired by @Unmitigated's input**

```js
function reverseKeys (obj) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .reverse()
      .map(
        ([k, v]) => {
          if (v.constructor === Object && v.constructor !== Array && v !== null) {
            return [k, reverseKeys(v)]
          } else if (v.constructor === Array && v !== null) {
            const a = []
            v.forEach(elem => {
              if ((elem.constructor === Object || elem.constructor === Array) && elem !== null) {
                a.push(reverseKeys(elem))
              } else {
                a.push(elem)
              }
            })
            return [k, a]
          } else {
            return [k, v]
          }
        }
      )
  )
}
```

Comment: A note on "order" in JS objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties

Comment: *I need to deep reverse the order of all keys in a JavaScript object.* - that's somewhat hard to believe. Why do you want that?

Comment: It's an object (something that's safest assumed to have no key ordering, even if the spec these days says there is a key ordering). Are you treating it as a tree where traversal order indicates node ordering? If so, look at using an actual tree data structure instead, because JS key ordering is based on insertion/declaration order. You'd have to unset `a` and `b` and then readd them, rather than "moving `c`", which just gets weirder and weirder the more keys you have... use a proper data structure =)

Comment: Understood - unfortunately the library json-schema-faker reverses the properties when we generate JSON samples from JSON schema. Users. of our tool is not so happy so I had to quickly write a reverser for the reversed structure... I think I will raise an issue as well in the json-schema-faker Github repo. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` over `Object.entries` recursively.

```js
let o = {
  a: 'val1',
  b: 'val2',
  c: {
    ca: 'val3',
    cb: 'val4'
  },
  d: [{a : 1, b : 2}, {c: 3}]
};
function reverseKeys(obj) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) return [...obj].reverse().map(reverseKeys);
  if (Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype) 
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).reverse()
      .map(([k, v]) => [k, reverseKeys(v)]));
  return obj;
}
console.log(reverseKeys(o));
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the fast answer, it seems to work :)

Comment: It works, but it's also crazy inefficient, so you probably still want to actually use the right data structure for the job ;)

Comment: Understood - unfortunately the library `json-schema-faker` reverses the properties when we generate JSON samples from JSON schema. Users. of our tool is not so happy so I had to quickly write a reverser for the reversed structure... I think I will raise an issue as well in the `json-schema-faker` Github repo. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @Unmitigated any idea why it does this to an array:
`{ a: [ { a1: 'val1' }, { a2: 'val2' } ] }` -> 
`{ a: { '0': { a1: 'val1' }, '1': { a2: 'val2' } } }`

Comment: @Ben You may need to update the condition for reversing to `v.constructor === Object` or `Object.getPrototypeOf(v) === Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Unmitigated yup that certainly took away the `0` and `1` etc. but keys inside and array then do not get reversed - maybe not possible after all?
`{ a: [ { a1: 'val1', a2: 'val2' } ] }` to become `{ a: [ { a2: 'val2', a1: 'val1' } ] }`

Comment: @Ben I've updated my answer to support arrays. If you do not want arrays themselves to be reversed, remove the `.reverse()` in `[...obj].reverse().map(...)`.